# Updating multi taxonomy field with processbatchdata

Tags: sharepoint-server, ssom

I'm trying to update a multi managed metadata /taxonomy field using sharepoint SSOM's bulk update method ProcessBatchData.

im passing this kind of string
  `batchXML.Append("<SetVar Name=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#ImplementingMissions_SC\">0;#Switzerland|6272ddcd-eaf0-4a7e-9a8a-023079a6853f</SetVar>");`

It runs successfully but doesn't update anything in the list.

Any leads would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way it works for me:

```
batchXML.Append("<SetVar Name=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#ImplementingMissions_SC\">1;#;#2;#;#3</SetVar>");
```

Where 1, 2 and 3 are the WssIDs of the terms (obviously, they can be any other number in your site collection).

Notice that these values are separated by ;#;# (yes, ;# two times).